# Permission denied when attempting to use input.exec plugin

Tags: python, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-plugins

I have written a python script that prints out metrics so that I can add them to an influxdb. The script works as my local user. It also works as the `telegraf` user.

However, the script fails when it runs as part of telegraf:

```
$ /usr/bin/telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -config-directory /etc/telegraf/telegraf.d --test
2019-03-29T19:21:48Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.10.1
2019-03-29T19:21:48Z E! [inputs.exec]: Error in plugin: exec: fork/exec /usr/lib/telegraf/custom-plugins/polltest.py: permission denied for command '/usr/lib/telegraf/custom-plugins/polltest.py'
...
```

If I run this as the telegraf user, though, it works as expected:

```
$ sudo -u telegraf /usr/lib/telegraf/custom-plugins/polltest.py
ups,hostname=ups1 battery.charge=100
ups,hostname=ups1 battery.runtime=2622
ups,hostname=ups1 battery.type="PbAC"
...
```

The script is owned and executable by telegraf:

```
$ ls -la /usr/lib/telegraf/custom-plugins/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Mar 29 14:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root     4096 Mar 29 14:06 ../
-rwxr--r-- 1 telegraf telegraf  906 Mar 29 14:15 polltest.py*
```

My telegraf.conf file points to the appropriate location:

```
[[inputs.exec]]
  commands = [
     "/usr/lib/telegraf/custom-plugins/polltest.py"
  ]
  timeout = "5s"
  data_format = "influx"
```

Finally, the script itself if pretty basic:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/upsc", "tripplite"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, encoding="utf8")

for result in p1.stdout:
      key, value = result.split(":")
      measurement = "ups"
      tags = "hostname=ups1"
      value = value.strip()
      # Check if our value is a number. If it's not, surround it in quotes. 
      # Don't actually use the float() value, as some numbers are returns as 
      # valid integers
      try:
              _ = float(value)
              field = f'{key}={value}'
      except ValueError:
              field = f'{key}="{value}"'
      influx_line_protocol = f"{measurement},{tags} {field}"
      print(influx_line_protocol)
```

What do I need to change so that this script is executed by telegraf without the permissions error?

Answer (score 0):

In the first attempt you are running telegraf as your own user that has not permission. Try with `systemctl start telegraf`.